# Understanding the mechanics of fold_right

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions, fold

Problem:Define the function `mapf` whose first argument is a unary function, and second argument list. The result is a list of the function applied to each element of the argument list. Write a one-liner using fold_right, and not a recursive function.

Solution:

```
let mapf fn list = fold_right (fun h t -> fn h :: t) list []
```

I don't understand how that solves the problem because fold_right computes a function with the list arguments in a recursive way, so it returns a value and not a list. I neither understand what the following notation means:

```
fun h t -> fn h :: t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two questions are related. It's true that `fold_right` returns a value, but a list is a value!

The `::` operator adds a new element to the beginning of a list. So the value computed by this application of `fold_right` is indeed a list.

Another way to think of this might be as follows. If you use `fold_right` with the `+` operator you compute a value like so:

```
fold_right (+) [1; 2; 3] 0 =>
1 + 2 + 3 + 0 =>
6
```

If you use `fold_right` with the `::` operator, you compute a value like so:

```
fold_right (::) [1; 2; 3] [] =>
1 :: 2 :: 3 :: [] =>
[1; 2; 3]
```

This isn't theoretical, it works exactly like this in the REPL:

```
# List.fold_right (+) [1; 2; 3] 0;;
- : int = 6
# List.fold_right (fun a b -> a :: b) [1; 2; 3] [];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

(You need to write `fun a b -> a :: b` because the `::` notation can't actuallly be used as a stand-alone function. Unfortunately.)

Note that it's completely legitimate to write a list using the `::` operator yourself:

```
# 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: [];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

**Update**

First, `fun x y -> expr` is the notation for a "lambda" in OCaml, i.e., for a function literal.

The function `fun h t -> fn h :: t` takes two values `h` and `t`. It applies the function `fn` to h, and returns a new list with this new value at the front of `t`.

From a typing standpoint, the value `h` must be the right type to pass to `fn`, and `fn` must return a value of the right type to be in the list `t`.

You could parenthesize it like this: `fun h t -> (fn h) :: t`, if that makes it clearer.

The function `fun a b -> a :: b` is similar except that it just puts `a` directly onto the list `b`. It doesn't apply any function. In essence, it does just what the `::` operator does.

From a typing standpoint, `a` has to be the right type to be an element of the list `b`.

**Update 2**

If you're trying to understand what a lambda is, one way of looking at it is that it's just a handy way to write a function that's reasonably small. You can easily write your given code without the lambda:

```
let mapf fn list =
    let helper h t = fn h :: t in
    List.fold_right helper list []
```

Instead of a lambda, this version has a locally declared function named `helper`.

Another way of looking at it is that *all* functions are lambdas. The idiomatic way of writing a function:

```
let f x y = x + y
```

is just a handy abbreviation for a version with an explicit lambda:

```
let f = fun x y -> x + y
```

So, really, a lambda isn't a special kind of function. It's exactly like any other function. It's just a notational choice.

Comment: so how do you interpret fun a b -> a :: b? and fun h t -> fn h :: t)

Comment: I will update my answer, there's no room in a comment.

Comment: I think I understand. Lambda expressions in ocaml are functions that express a certain behavior of other functions.

Comment: This is true, but a little strange way of looking at it. A lambda is just a function, not a special kind of function. All functions use other functions unless they're extremely trivial.

Comment: I would say, that lambda is just an anonymous function. You can define a function using the `let` notation, or you can just throw it in, using this `fun` notation. Everywhere where lambda is used, a normal function can be used, and vice verse.